# ReactJS: Sorting an array of data from the state that is passed to a component as a props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a React application and I am using Redux to store the state. I have the following data.

menu.data.js:

```
export default [
    {
        "_id": "c0daac6ab8954a40606dd8b81d24a0ef",
        "name": "Entree",
        "rank": "0",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "Curry Puffs",
                "price": 14,
                "_id": "615caa7dd573bcf84781c9e4382b520d"
            },
            {
                "title": "Spring Rolls",
                "price": 12,
                "_id": "542f711856b7854b71d9862797620e23"
            },
            {
                "title": "Tandoori Cauliflower",
                "price": 20,
                "_id": "f0c0f2fa02e392ad4e74dfaaf6068fb1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "934aeba1e96e6d6a4207cd5ba207b52a",
        "name": "Lunch",
        "rank": "1",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "Spaghetti",
                "price": 20,
                "_id": "db414e2b9951ed621fbf6fb40df36ee3"
            },
            {
                "title": "Spaghetti",
                "price": 20,
                "_id": "253592733a8f7835f390d3d9ed8bda95"
            },
            {
                "title": "Spaghetti",
                "price": 20,
                "_id": "a22741f27a346cda93d3cf752e371779"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import MenuCategory from '../../components/menu-category/menu-category.component'
import NewCategoryButton from '../../components/new-category-button/new-category-button.component';

import './menu.styles.scss';

const MenuPage = props => {

    console.log("Printing the menu");
    console.log(props.menu);

    const menuItems = props.menu;
    menuItems.sort((a,b) => (a.rank < b.rank) ? 1 : -1);

    console.log("After sorting the items");
    console.log(menuItems);

    return (
        <div className='menu-page'>
            {props.menu ? props.menu.map(category => <MenuCategory key={category._id} {...category} />) : null}
            {props.currentUser ? <NewCategoryButton /> : null}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentUser: state.user.currentUser,
    menu: state.menu
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MenuPage);
```

In the above code, I am sorting the objects from `menu.data.js` in descending order with respect to the rank. The data from `menu.data.js` is passed to the `MenuPage` component as a props.

Through sorting the menu data, the `Lunch` object will come before the `Entree` object in the `menuItems` array.

However, I have noticed that when I console.log() `props.menu` and the `menuItems` array, they are both the same, despite the fact that I have only sorted `menuItems`.

[image]

As a result, when I render the data, the items in the Lunch category are displayed before the items in the Entree category, even though I am mapping through `props.menu` and not `menuItems`. When I remove the code that assigns `props.menu` to `menuItems` and then sorts `menuItems`, the `Entree` items are displayed before the `Lunch` items. I.e.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';

    import MenuCategory from '../../components/menu-category/menu-category.component'
    import NewCategoryButton from '../../components/new-category-button/new-category-button.component';

    import './menu.styles.scss';

    const MenuPage = props => {    

        return (
            <div className='menu-page'>
                {props.menu ? props.menu.map(category => <MenuCategory key={category._id} {...category} />) : null}
                {props.currentUser ? <NewCategoryButton /> : null}
            </div>
        )
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        currentUser: state.user.currentUser,
        menu: state.menu
    })

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MenuPage);
```

I am not sure why this is occurring. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have assigned the array by reference like:

```
const a = [1, 3, 2]
const b = a
```

Now, if you sort `b`, then `a` is also automatically sorted like:

```js
const a = [1, 3, 2]
const b = a
b.sort()
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

Only way to resolve that would be to create a clone of the array `a` and then assign that to `b` like:

```js
const a = [1, 3, 2]
const b = [...a] // clone array using spread syntax
b.sort()
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

Now, you can see only `b` is sorted and `a` is still the same.